# jQuery Autocomplete problem - Shift Key behaves same as Return Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

See: http://www.airbnb.com/

In the search bar, start typing "san f" (no quotes, all lowercase), then hit Return (or Enter). "San Francisco" is autocompleted. This is good!

Now clear the search field and start over. type "San F" and boom - "San Francisco" is autocompleted as soon as you hit Shift. This is not expected.

This happens in FF & Safari, but is untested elsewhere. I've looked through the jQuery Autocomplete Source Code and everything looks normal.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: its not just shift. its tab too. basically your code divides the keyboard into three categories....either characters to enter words, key codes that do nothing and key codes that confirm like tab, shift and enter. They are probably not based in a particular keycode bla = bla but rather a range of them

Answer (score 2):

**Try Search option in autocomplete as follow:**

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
    search: function( event, ui ) {
       if(event.which == 16 || event.which == 17 )
        event.preventDefault();  
    }
});
```

Comment: After all these years, this answer helped me. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

**To get around this issue:**

To the KEY object add:

```
    SHIFT: 16,
    CTRL: 17,
    ALT: 18
```

And to the very top of the onChange function add:

```
if ( jQuery.inArray(lastKeyPressCode, [KEY.SHIFT, KEY.CTRL,
       KEY.ALT]) !== -1 )
                return;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in the autocomple configuration `autoFill: true` is defined. Remove this one it will solve the problem.But in that case after writing of the "san f" it will not automaticaly fill the "san Francisco, CA".